# How to properly check user input in php?

Tags: php, validation

I have a function that checks user input and wanted to know if it prevents against all attacks of this sort. Also, if I wanted to include this function on each page that needed it could I put it in a php page of its own then 'include()' it into them pages where it's required. Thanks.

```
function secure_data($value)
{
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
if (function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string" )) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
} else {
    $value = addslashes($value);
}
return $value;
}
```

Comment: The key in your question lies in explaining by what you mean by "Attacks of this sort". If you know which sorts - you can better research how to protect against them..

Comment: What are you trying to protect? It may seem that you are trying to protect against SQL injection. If that is the case you should rather just use PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using quotes, I'm assuming that your main question is how to protect against SQL injections, if I'm not mistaken. (Note: securing against SQL-injection is something else then securing against for example Cross Site Scripting!); and will not guarantee you a secure application.

The best solution for SQL injection is not to use this function, but to use prepared statements with either mysqli or PDO.
(See: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) )

**Other interesting links:**

Background information on sql injection:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Other validation:
http://www.faqs.org/docs/gazette/superglobals.html

Input validation from OWASP:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation